Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class base/security/config/WebSecurityAutoConfiguration$StandardSecurityConfig.class
`{"instant":{"epochSecond":1714980804,"nanoOfSecond":741495900},"thread":"main","level":"ERROR","loggerName":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","message":"Application run failed","thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"Unable to start web server","message":"Unable to start web server","name":"org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException","cause":{"commonElementCount":7,"localizedMessage":"Unable to start embedded Tomcat","message":"Unable to start embedded Tomcat","name":"org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException","cause":{"commonElementCount":7,"localizedMessage":"Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.webSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class [com/fis/epo/base/security/config/WebSecurityAutoConfiguration$StandardSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointWebExtensionConfiguration$MvcAdditionalHealthEndpointPathsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AdditionalHealthEndpointPathsWebMvcHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: Failed to extract parameter names for public void com.fis.epo.base.security.config.RolesCacheEndpoint.deleteCachByKey(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)","message":"Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.webSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/fis/epo/base/security/config/WebSecurityAutoConfiguration$StandardSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointWebExtensionConfiguration$MvcAdditionalHealthEndpointPathsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AdditionalHealthEndpointPathsWebMvcHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: Failed to extract parameter names for public void com.fis.epo.base.security.config.RolesCacheEndpoint.deleteCachByKey(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)","name":"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException","cause":{"commonElementCount":7,"localizedMessage":"Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/fis/epo/base/security/config/WebSecurityAutoConfiguration$StandardSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource

Please include more information and ask a proper question that just post some sort of exception. Voted to close

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
